# Page doesn't link to stylesheet, Firebug shows it does

Tags: html, css, xampp

I wrote a quick page and am trying to center a div element.  I wrote an external stylesheet and linked it with  within the head section.  Firebug shows the stylesheet when I load the page (localhost, using XAMPP) but the style isn't being applied.  When I add the style to the div tage (style="") and use the same text as in the external, it works just fine -- but no go on the external.  I've tried absolute pathing and relative.

Is there possibly a quirk with using XAMPP and stylesheets on localhost?

In case you need it (should be fine, copy and paste into the in-tag style and it works), here's the applicable section in the external:
    div.mainLogo {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0px auto;}

I'm using Firefox 27.0.1

Comment: When you load the page, check in firebug if the style is linked correctly by clicking on it and checking if it does not return a 404. You can do that using view source as well.

Comment: Check the complete request from the stylesheet. response headers OK? **Without code we can only guess**. How you import the Stylesheet, over **<link>**-Tag, **@import**,..?

Comment: If you post your import code we'll be able to tell you what's wrong.

Comment: This is the way it's linked in the head section:<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="McsOpenStyle.css" />

Comment: No 404 when I open in Firebug or source.  In firebug, I click it and it shows me the stylesheet -- when I click an element, it shows me the styles from the sheet associated with that element just like it should.

Comment: I figured it out -- I was referring to a div class rather than a div ID.  Thanks for all the help, guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wild guess  -

Since the external stylesheet is loading perfectly, and inline style is being applyed,

the problem must be with your css selector. check how you are referring to the element from external stylesheet, as in the case of inline styling selector is not required.

Comment: That was it, I was referring to a div class, not a div id.